# PHPUnit alert on failure, by email or text?

Tags: php, unit-testing, cron, phpunit

My website has an API, which essentially is a data scraping API for a number of sites. If any of the other sites change, my API breaks. I need my API to be as stable as possible, and if it breaks I need to update it as quickly as possible.

In order to ensure that it is working properly, I have written a suite of PHPUnit tests which ensure that it is working as expected.

I'd like these tests to run periodically, maybe once a day, perhaps more frequently depending of how resource-intensive they are. I could set up a cron job which runs PHPUnit every so often, and I'd like to be alerted, either by email or text, when any of the PHPUnit tests fails, so I can fix the API promptly. As far as I can tell, there are no options for doing this in PHPUnit itself which is a shame. What is the best way to set this up?

Comment: Did I understand that right: You have a live page, that are running unit tests all the time? Did they run with _every_ request? Thats sounds scary to me ^^ You should consider using a continous integration environment _before_ publishing your app. And they can also email you :)

Comment: No, they aren't running all the time. I will update the question with more information.

Comment: @KingCrunch is right. Unit tests are to be run before the code go live, not while it is live. And I don't think it's a shame for PHPUnit not to email results. It's a unit testing framework, not a continuous integration application.

Comment: Also two other reason, that speaks against your plan: 1. If your app is tested and goes live, the unit tests will never fail anymore. No reason to run them, even periodically. 2. Unittest _will_ get very resource-intensive.

Comment: The key is that the sites that the application scrapes may change without Jason changing his code. Thus these are more like integration/monitoring tests that will run periodically to detect that the code needs to change in response to the source data format changing. The plan is sound.

Comment: The questioner is using an application called PHPUnit. That doesn't mean that they are or should be practising unit testing. This is about monitoring a live website, which can go down for reasons unrelated to the code, like a fire at the data centre or an upaid hosting bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get yourself a nice little continuous integration environment. I use [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/). You can also use it with [phpUnderControl](http://phpundercontrol.org) (which I personally don't use because of the variety of languages I'm coding in).

You can automate builds using [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org) (or [Phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/), if you really want a PHP solution). You can setup emails, unit testing, automated nightlies, etc.

Just make sure to use the JUnit logging format in PHPUnit (`--log-junit` switch).

Comment: I would use normally use phing, but you should also be able set the CI tool to run PHPUnit directly if you don't want the complexity of something in between.

Answer (score 3):

you should be using something like hudson / jenkins that preforms the tests when the code is changed. eg using pre/post commit hooks of your favourite source control app.

This way you wont ever have broken code deployed (with capistrano) to a live server.

http://hudson-ci.org/

http://jenkins-ci.org/

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki

As for emailing when there are errors, there is some code like that around. There is a CakePHP plugin that you could use/port or get ideas from

https://github.com/joebeeson/referee

Answer (score 2):

To provide some more resources:

For setting up a CI ([continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)) Server (the thing that runs your tests) I'd strongly suggest taking a look at **[jenkins-php.org](http://jenkins-php.org)**.

From my personal experience Jenkins is way easier to get running and to work with compared to phpundercontrol. Also more stable and actively developed.

Jenkins has a *ton* of Plugins that can do any sort of notification for you if you don't want to "just get an email" but a instant message or a irc message for example.

It's darn easy to set up [(**self promotion**)](http://edorian.posterous.com/setting-up-jenkins-for-php-projects) way less trouble to administrate/maintain and "just works" for pretty much any use case.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be to run the tests in a cron job and pipe the output to your email address.

[Check the article](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/schedule_tasks_on_linux_using_crontab/) and scroll to the section about emailing the CRON JOB.

Comment: The OP only wants an email when there's a failure. Is there a way to stop PHPUnit producing output for passing tests?